# Using Triggers on GPIO.RaspberryPi3 to send Emails

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I am new to python and I have some troubles using the GPIOs of a RPi3 to start executing parts of a python-script.

To make it simple, i have a machine that can give out a Digital trigger (similar to a mechanical switch) whenever it’s on hold, or the program is aborted ect..
What I want is for the Raspberry to send an Email whenever a given GPIO is triggered.

For example:

-when it’s on hold, the machine triggers the Pin 21

-when it’s aborted, the machine triggers the Pin 20

I wrote the following code:

```
import smtplib
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import os.path
from time import gmtime, strftime, sleep
import datetime as dt


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Input GPIO for trigger
GPIO_Hold=21
GPIO_Abort=20


#Setup Pins
GPIO.setup(GPIO_Hold, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_Abort, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


#Get get time for when the programm was started
t = dt.datetime.now()

#Function for Email
def send_mail(alert):
    HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
    PORT = 587
    SUBJECT = "[UPDATE] Machine"
    TO = "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM"
    FROM = "RPI@EMAIL.COM"
    PWD = "RPi"
    text = alert
    BODY = string.join(("from: %s" %FROM, "to: %s" %TO,"Subject: %s" %SUBJECT, "     ", text), "\r\n")
    s = smtplib.SMTP(HOST,PORT)
    s.set_debuglevel(1)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.login(FROM, PWD)
    s.sendmail(FROM,[TO],BODY)
    s.quit

#Function for Logbook file for sent infos
def log_book(alert):
    time_stamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    f= open("logbook12K.txt",'a+')
    f.write(time_stamp + " // " + alert + "\n")
    f.close()

# Begin Loop
try:
    while True:
        print("Waiting for Trigger...")


#If Test on Hold
        if GPIO.wait_for_edge(GPIO_Hold, GPIO.FALLING):
            alert = "Test on Hold"
            log_book(alert)
            send_mail(alert)
            sleep (1)

#If test aborted
        elif GPIO.wait_for_edge(GPIO_Abort, GPIO.FALLING):
            alert = "Test Aborted"
            log_book(alert)
            send_mail(alert)
            sleep (1)




except KeyboardInterrupt: # trap a CTRL+C keyboard interrupt
  GPIO.cleanup() # resets all GPIO ports used by this program
```

I am aware that `GPIO.wait_for_edge(GPIO_Abort, GPIO.FALLING)` isnt the best solution, but using `GPIO.event_detected(channel)` won’t work either.
When on hold, my machine will constantly trigger the pin 21, and i don’t want the RPi3 to constantly send Billions of Emails, so i cant just use `if GPIO.input(GPIO_Hold)`.

The `GPIO.event_detected(channel)` does only detect a change, so it will also send a "Machine on Hold" update, when the machine is started again and the trigger back to normal.
Also i don’t really know if `GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback)` could be useful since i cannot throw a variable in the callback function.

Maybe by putting the `def send_mail(alert):` and `def log_book(alert):` into a bigger, overall funtion?

I hope i was clear enough..
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question? To only send the email for 'hold' and 'abort' status only once?

Comment: When the maschine gets on hold/abort, it uses some sort of switch and change its state from 0 to 1. This change of state triggers the GPIO on the raspberry (i mesure 3,3V on the pin) I want the raspberry to send ONE email whenever a given GPIO is triggered. When i start the machine again, it sets everything back to 0 and no mail is sent until in aborts or holds again ..

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for those who might be intrested:

```
import smtplib
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import gmtime, strftime, sleep
import datetime as dt


GPIO_Hold=21
GPIO_Abort=20

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  

GPIO.setup(GPIO_Hold, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_Abort, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def email_logbook(channel):

    if channel == GPIO_Hold:
        alert = " Hold"
        print("Send mail "+alert)
        #Function for Logbook file for sent infos
        print("Logbook "+alert)

    elif channel== GPIO_Abort:
        alert = " Aborted"
        print("Send mail "+alert)
        #Function for Logbook file for sent infos
        print("Logbook "+alert)

GPIO.add_event_detect(GPIO_Hold, GPIO.FALLING, callback=email_logbook, bouncetime=1000)     
GPIO.add_event_detect(GPIO_Abort, GPIO.FALLING, callback=email_logbook, bouncetime=1000)    

count=0
try:
    while True: 
        count=count+1

except KeyboardInterrupt:  
    GPIO.cleanup()       # clean up GPIO on CTRL+C exit

GPIO.cleanup()           # clean up GPIO
```

You have to do your cases in the callback function with `if` & `elif` where you check the GPIO-Pins for an event